# how to add image plugin under rteplugins for richtext component

Tags: java, javascript, content-management-system, richtextbox, aem

I have a rich text component, I need to configure it in such a way that we can **drag and drop** the **image** in the rich text component.For that under **rte plugins** I have added one plugin called **image** which is of **primary type nt:unstructured** having features of String[] and value as *.Even,after adding that above image plugin, Im not able to drag and drop the image.Please let me know what I have done wrong.

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to documentation:

> To activate all features for that plugin:
>   Name features
>   Type String
>   Value * (asterisk)
>
> To activate specific features (any not explicitly defined will be deactivated):
>   Name features
>   Type String[] (multi-string; set Type to String and click Multi in CRXDE Lite)
>   Value(s) set to one, or more, feature values
>
> Even if you are only setting one specific value of features you do
>   have to use String[].
>   String is only valid when defining features as *.

So if your type is String[], you have to explicitly put the feature name.
I suggest you to change String[] to String ("*" in this situation will be ok).
This
adds context menu entries for setting some image properties (currently only alignment is supported).

Answer (score 0):

The Richtext Image plugin (and indeed most of the rtePlugins) seems to only be compatible with Mozilla Firefox. Try that browser and see if it works.